# Problems in installing firefox 23 on centos 6.3 ( libpangoft2-1.0.so.0)

Tags: centos

XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /home/xd/firefox/firefox/libxul.so:
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.

I cannot find a way to install libpangoft2-1.0.so.0
After  searching, it *seemed* to me that the library will be in the pango package. Accordingly, I tried yum install pango but get this
Package pango-1.28.1-7.el6_3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

How do I get this installed.

PS: It is surprising that centos 6.3 needs to be upgraded to install firefox 23. I had to install libstdc++.i686, dbus-glib.i686 and it seems I have to install some more to get this browser to work. Same results with chrome

Comment: Where is the Firefox package coming from?

Comment: Thanks for response. I downloaded it from firefox website.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have some sort of library mismatch. Usually this sort of error is one of these::

1. You have architecture mismatch, e.g. are trying to run a 32-bit Firefox on a mostly 64-bit system, which is very likely to be missing some 32-bit counterparts even of the standard packages (e.g. libstdc++ you mentioned).
2. Your system is too old for latest Firefox - while this might come as a surprise, it is caused by Firefox using often quite recent versions of libraries, which are not present in enterprise grade OS (Debian stable, RHEL, SLE - in alphabetical order).

Of these, number 1. seems more likely to me - it's quite unlikely you'd have 32-bit version of Pango installed on your 64-bit system. You'll need the corresponding 32-bit compatibility package. Also please note that version 1.28 might be the latest from CentOS' (RHEL) perspective, but the upstream is at 1.33.x.